# How this site shows a neat HTML box before you leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On this site:  http://shirtjs.com/product-category/collections/zeptojs/

when you move your cursor out of the html page (about to go close the tab) they show a "Wait Before You Leave!" modal centered div.

TLDR:

This doesn't occur if you 'leave' the HTML page through the sides or bottom of your browser window.

Is it a common JS library, custom made, ...

There's like 2,000,000 libraries loaded on their site! Haven't been able to trace their JS code effectively to get to the bottom of this.

Any idea how they do it?

Comment: Probably one line horizontally 1px high with a hover event on the top of the page.

Comment: na, you can go crazy fast and it still works.

Comment: Then maybe on hover out of the body. Mystery solved.

Comment: no because it doesnt trigger if the body is left from eighter side or the bottom of the window.

Comment: If it helps, it seems like they may be using this plugin: http://codecanyon.net/item/layered-popups-for-wordpress/5978263

Comment: it's similar but this pops if you leave the viewport from eighter sides and the bottom. On my mac the modal appears every time I move my mouse out of the page from the bottom to start an app or switch. Really annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

ouibounce lib.

https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce

Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: Good sleuthing :) In the future, in case it helps: https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/9WvgE2K2QTF (note that you can also filter to view only events specifically bound to the node you're looking at).